# How to search games by its publisher in Steam

Tags: steam

For example I want to search for games developed or published by *Valve* in Steam, But I can't figure it out how?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Worth looking on Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Valve_Corporation_video_games

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given you know the Developer you want to search for:

Go to a known game by that developer and click on their name on the right side, where the game info lays. For Valve it goes to [this list page](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?developer=Valve)

Similarly you can [click on the Publisher](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?publisher=Valve) to see that company's published games

In theory, you should be able to type in the search bar

> Developer: Valve

or

> Publisher: Valve

but that doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: Developer != Publisher. 
You get 18 Pages of results for http://store.steampowered.com/search/?publisher=Ubisoft but only 3 pages for http://store.steampowered.com/search/?developer=Ubisoft

Comment: @xhadon badly worded on my side, fixed.

Comment: So, I should add that there is no way to search directly for Publisher or Developers! - If I use Search  - search/?term=Developer%3A+Valve - its results will be so far- BTW thanks